# Replace of NCHAR(1600) is not working on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-server-collation

When I run bellow code the `NCHAR(1600)` is not replaced

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'foo' + NCHAR(1600), NCHAR(1600), '**') --> output: fooـ
```

- My database collation is `Persian_100_CI_AI`
- The default collation of SQL server is `Persian_100_CI_AI` too
- My SQL server version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU3-GDR) (KB4052987) - 14.0.3015.40 (X64)`

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some characters aren't matched well in certain collations. As a result some will be matched against others when they aren't the same, and others may end up not being matched even though they are.

`REPLACE` uses collations and so it appears that the matching of the same character isn't working. In such cases, it's often therefore an idea to use a different collation inside the `REPLACE`, and if you need to return to the original collation, use `COLLATE` again outside:

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'foo' + NCHAR(1600) COLLATE Persian_100_BIN, NCHAR(1600), '**') COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AI;
```

Comment: You should [mention that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5dfa32a9b13ea6c2e89b2dce1f146ed5) Larnu

Comment: Depends on the [version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5dfa32a9b13ea6c2e89b2dce1f146ed5) @Sami. As they haven't mentioned one I assumed they have the latest, but the workaround is to use a sub query.

Comment: Documentations for Replace function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

We can use **REPLICATE** too, instead of writing collation at high level, just need concatenation of * after after the N'foo' value right?

```
SELECT CONCAT(N'foo',REPLICATE('*',1600))
```